# Getting C202 and C141 errors in Keil

Tags: c, keil

I've been trying to write c code in keil to **convert string to binary**. While compiling, the code is running into `C202` and `C141` errors.
I'm new  to keil and I've  no idea regarding those errors.

The errors are:

```
main.c(13): error C202: 'i': undefined identifier
main.c(17): error C141: syntax error near 'int', expected 'sizeof'
```

Any help would be appreciated. Here's the Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>




int main(){
         char *s = "Hello"; 
   int n = strlen(s);


for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
{
    // convert each char to
    // ASCII value
     int val =  (int)(s[i]);

    // Convert ASCII value to binary
    char* bin;
    while (val > 0)
    {
        if(val % 2) 
                bin[i]  =1; 
             else   
                bin[i] = 0;
        val /= 2;
    }
    bin =  strrev(bin);

   
}
    
    return bin;
```

}

Comment: Where do you declare `i`?

Comment: I tried both i.e. declaring int i and without declaring. Got same error both time.

Comment: Some compilers are too old to understand the `for` loop with a variable definition. Move `int i;` before the loop. The second error can be a follow-up because of the first error. -- What version of which Keil compiler do you use?

Comment: OT: You defined a pointer `bin` to some characters, but it is not initialized, the pointer has an undefined value.

Comment: @thebusybee thank you for reaching out. Moving `int i;` before the for loop worked absolutely fine. I just declared `char bin[100]` before for loop. There are not errors anymore but  `strrev`  is still giving some errors errors. I think that my logic isn't good enough.

Comment: Feel free to post another question if you need help. But you might want to try to debug it yourself. Run your code in the debugger and watch your variables.